# Evaluation of gensim Doc2Vec model for Recommendations

Tags: nlp, gensim, recommendation-engine, evaluation, doc2vec

I have developed a pipeline to extract text from documents, preprocess the text, and train a gensim Doc2vec model on given documents. Given a document in my corpus, I would like to recommend other documents in the corpus.

I want to know how I can evaluate my model without having a pre-defined list of "good" recommendations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple self-check that can be used to catch some big problems with a `Doc2Vec` model training pipeline – like gross misparameterizations, or insufficient data/epochs – is to re-infer vectors for the training texts (using `.infer_vector()`), and check that generally:

1. the bulk-trained vector for the same text is "close to" the re-inferred vector - such as its nearest-neighbor, or one of the top neighbors, in a `.most_similar()` operation on the re-inferred text
2. the overall list of nearest-neighbors (from `.most_similar()`) for the bulk-trained vector, & the re-inferred vector, are very similar.

They won't necessarily be identical, for reasons explained in [Q11 & Q12 of the Gensim Project FAQ](https://github.com/RARE-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism), but if they're wildly-different, then something foundational has gone wrong, like:

- insufficient (in quantity or quality/form) training data
- misparameterizations, like too few epochs or too-large (overfitting-prone) vectors for the quantity of data

Ultimately, though, the variety of data sources & intended uses & possible dimensions of "recommendation-worthy" mean that you need cusomt inputs, based on your project's needs, usually from the intended audience (or your own ability to simulate/represent it).

In the [original paper introducing the "Paragraph Vector" algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4053) (what's inside the `Doc2Vec` class), and a [followup evaluating it on Wikipedia & arXiv articles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.07998), several of the evaluations used triplets of documents, where 2 of the triplet were conjectured to be "necessarily similar" based on some preexisting system's groupings, and the 3rd randomly-chosen.

The algorithm's performance, and relative performance under different parameter choices, was scored based on how often it placed the 2 presumptively-related documents closer-together than the 3rd randomly-chosen document.

For example, one of the original paper's evaluations use brief search-engine-result snippets as documents, and considered any 2 documents that appeared as sibling top-10 results for the same query as presumptively-related. Two of the followup paper's evaluation used the human-curated categories of Wikipedia or arXiv as signalling that articles of the same category should be presumptively-related.

It's imperfect, but allowed the creation of large evaluation sets from already-existing systems/data, which generally pointed results in the same direction as human senses-of-relatedness.

Perhaps you can find a similar preexisting guide for your data. Or, as you perform ad-hoc checking, be sure to *capture every judgement you make*, so that it becomes, over time, a growing dataset of desirable pairings that are either (a) better than some other result that was co-presented; or (b) just "presumably good enough" that they usually should rank higher than other random 3rd documents. A large amount of imprecision in such desirability-data is tolerable, as it can even out as the set of probe-pairings grows, and the power of being able to automate bulk quantitative evaluations (reusing old assessments against new parameters/models) drives far more overall improvement than any small glitches in the evaluations cost.